# Cannot access C drive via VPN

Tags: vpn

We have configured VPN in windows 2008 server. Two NIC one public and a loopback adapter with private IP 192.168.2.200.

We can connect via VPN for any users in system and can check the shares \192.168.2.200, however If we try to connect drive \192.168.2.200\c$ for any users other than administrator it gives 'Logon unsuccessful' message. Only administrator can connect.

Now we have shared the C drive to gain access to files for the users connecting to system. I have checked with Firewall and other network and share settings in the server which is fine.

Any idea will be highly appreciated!.

Comment: I bet you that you can't access C$ even within you network. Without VPN involved.

Comment: I could not get you exactly. Can you add more clarity on the above statement. If I am doing anything wrong let me know.

Comment: C$ is an administrative share. Only administrators are allowed to access. This is by design.

Comment: I don't see any reason to down vote. I think this post provides valuable learning lessons to anyone who may unknowingly be attempting the same thing. Was the downvote a point to say the author is not as smart as you or do you not see any value in this post at all?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It has been fixed finally. The problem is due to UAC settings where by default the access is restricted even though you are in administrator group. I have enabled two policy settings in UAC and finally the access are granted for the users.

Answer (score 4):

Thats how its supposed to be. Shares with a $ after it are administrative shares and thus you have to be an administrator to get to it.

Edit: After verifying pauskas comment it would appear that only the default shares like that are administrator equivalent only.

Comment: Not correct - you can create shares with $ signs to hide it but allow access for any user. It's just the default administrative shares that are administrator-only.

Comment: Well hell, you learn something new every day.